# Custom recipe that doesn't add any files

Tags: bitbake, recipe, petalinux

I am trying to add a recipe to PetaLinux which only runs commands, adding new users.
Aside from the pre-amble `SUMMARY`, `LICENCE` etc here is what I have:

```
inherit extrausers

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
  useradd -P newuser newuser; \
  "

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
```

This recipe is in recipes-apps, and it is enabled in `petalinux-config -c rootfs`
The petalinux image builds and boots fine, but the new user is not created.

Is this the correct way to add recipes which don't add files? If not, what is the correct way of adding recipes like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lowercase p and supply an encrypted password.

Get the encrypted password by running `openssl passwd <yourpassword>` on the command line:

```
~# openssl passwd newuser
o3ZhCFw5jSioM
```

Then add to your recipe:

```
useradd -p 'o3ZhCFw5jSioM' newuser
```